# Rails4 - fix deprecation warning

Tags: warnings, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade, deprecated

I haven't find a good "guide" to fix the deprecation warning upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 4.0.0. Then, there are some that I have encountered. Maybe can be useful for someone.

If you have encountered some others warning and its fix, feel free to add it.

Answer (score 0):

**Confirm in links**
Old code (this will be removed from Rails 4.1)

```
<%= link_to "My link", some_path, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

Should be

```
<%= link_to "My link", some_path, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

**Model 'find_all'**
Old code

```
MyModel.find(:all, :conditions => ['var = ? AND date = ?', 1, Date.today], :order => "date DESC")
```

Should be

```
MyModel.where('var = ? AND date = ?', 1, Date.today).order("date DESC")
```

**Model 'calculations'**
Old code

```
MyModel.sum(:score, :conditions => ['user_id = ?', 3])
```

Should be

```
MyModel.where('user_id = ?', 3).sum(:score)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice guide through changes in Rails 4. It's called `Rails 4: Zombie outlaws`. 
You can find it easily [on CodeSchool](http://rails4.codeschool.com/videos).